# Pomodoro Clock not beeping

Tags: javascript

```js
const audio = document.getElementById('beep');
audio.currentTime = 1.8;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    breakCount: 1,
    sessionCount: 1,
    clockCount: 1,
    currentTimer: 'Session',
    isPlaying: false
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.loop = undefined;
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.loop);
  }

  handlePlayPause = () => {
    const { isPlaying } = this.state;
    
    if(isPlaying) {
      clearInterval(this.loop);
      
      this.setState({
        isPlaying: false
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isPlaying: true
      });

      this.loop = setInterval(() => {
        const { 
          clockCount, 
          currentTimer, 
          breakCount, 
          sessionCount 
        } = this.state;
        
        if(clockCount === 0) {
          this.setState({
            currentTimer: (currentTimer === 'Session') ? 'Break' : 'Session',
            clockCount: (currentTimer === 'Session') ? (breakCount * 60) : (sessionCount * 60)
          });
          
          audio.play();
        } else {
          this.setState({
            clockCount: clockCount - 1
          });
        }
        
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
    //reset function to revert to an identical initial state//
  handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({
      breakCount: 5,
      sessionCount: 25,
      clockCount: 25 * 60,
      currentTimer: 'Session',
      isPlaying: false
    });
    //clear the time loop//
    clearInterval(this.loop);
    
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  }
//converts time to hh:mm format//
  convertToTime = (count) => {
    let minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    let seconds = count % 60;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? ('0'+minutes) : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? ('0'+seconds) : seconds;
    return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  }
  
  handleLengthChange = (count, timerType) => {
    const { 
      sessionCount, 
      breakCount, 
      isPlaying, 
      currentTimer
    } = this.state;
    
    
    //declare var newCount to be either session or breakcount + count//
    let newCount;
    
    if(timerType === 'session') {
      newCount = sessionCount + count;
    } else {
      newCount = breakCount + count;
    }
    //setState method applied towards newcount under condition that count is between 0 and 61// 
    if(newCount > 0 && newCount < 61 && !isPlaying) {
      this.setState({
        [`${timerType}Count`]: newCount
      });
      
      if(currentTimer.toLowerCase() === timerType) {
        this.setState({
          clockCount: newCount * 60
        })
      }
    }
  }
 
  render() {
    const { 
      breakCount, 
      sessionCount, 
      clockCount, 
      currentTimer,
      isPlaying
    } = this.state;
    
    const breakProps = {
      title: 'Break',
      count: breakCount,
      handleDecrease: () => this.handleLengthChange(-1, 'break'),
      handleIncrease: () => this.handleLengthChange(1, 'break')
    }
    
    const sessionProps = {
      title: 'Session',
      count: sessionCount,
      handleDecrease: () => this.handleLengthChange(-1, 'session'),
      handleIncrease: () => this.handleLengthChange(1, 'session'),
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="flex">
          <SetTimer {...breakProps} />
          <SetTimer {...sessionProps} />
        </div>
        
        <div className="clock-container">
          <h1 id="timer-label">{currentTimer}</h1>
          <span id="time-left">{this.convertToTime(clockCount)}</span>
               
          <div className="flex">
         <button id="start_stop" onClick={this.handlePlayPause}>
              {isPlaying ? (
                <i className="material-icons">pause_circle_filled</i> //isPlaying true
              ) : (
                <i className="material-icons">play_circle_filled</i> //is Playing false
              )}
            </button>
            
            &nbsp; &nbsp;
            
            <button id="reset" onClick={this.handleReset}>
              <i class="material-icons">
restart_alt
</i>
             </button>
          
          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>);
  }
}

//<i className="fas fa-sync" />


const SetTimer = (props) => {
  const id = props.title.toLowerCase();
  
  return (
    <div className="timer-container">
      <h2 id={`${id}-label`}>
        {props.title} Length
      </h2>
      <div className="flex actions-wrapper">
        <button id={`${id}-decrement`} onClick={props.handleDecrease}>
          <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
        </button>
        
        <span id={`${id}-length`}>{props.count}</span>
        
        <button id={`${id}-increment`} onClick={props.handleIncrease}>
          <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: #f8f8ff;
  background-color: #000080;
  font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

/*styling for input buttons*/
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: #f8f8ff;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #1affc6;

}




/*tucks the timer-container upward*/
.timer-container {
  margin: -30px 30px 30px;
  color: #e60000;  
}

.timer-container h2 {
  margin: 5px
}

.actions-wrapper span {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 60px;
}

/*clock portion*/
.clock-container {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}

/*styling for header above numeric clock*/
.clock-container h1 {
  margin: 2px;
}

/*Numeric clock styling*/
.clock-container span {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #1affc6;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>




<audio id="beep" preload="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rTzJIxBHKc" />

<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
```

I am working on the FreeCodeCamp Pomodoro Clock app project and unable to get the beeping sound to work.

Edit: Attached code via Stack Snippet.

In the HTML file I have included `<audio id="beep" preload="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rTzJIxBHKc" />`

In the Javascript file towards the top of the page I have included `const audio = document.getElementById('beep');`

I later call the "audio" object at around line 50 `audio.play();` for when the timer's session expires however I cannot get any audio to work.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question itself, not just a codepen link. Use the stack snippet feature to create a executable example. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't think you can use the URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rTzJIxBHKc in an audio element. The URL links to an HTML page, not an audio file.

Comment: @disinfor, Thanks for the heads up. Now I know how to better present my codes for easy access to fellow Stackoverflowers!!

Comment: @evolutionxbox, hey you are correct. I wanted to use the YouTube clip but it will not work. I used a corrected audio (.wav file) link within my HTML code and it now produces sound!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When utilizing the HTML  tag you cannot utilize YouTube links. You must utilize MP3, WAV, and OGG audio formats.